# Weird browser-related CSS column issue in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, responsive

I don't stumble upon browser-related issues when I'm working with WordPress development very often, but I'm having trouble finding the reason for this strange, although simple bug with Firefox/Edge (working OK with Chrome; not tested in other browsers).

The website: http://stitchwear.com.br/

In the home page, we have several products showcased. In the last column, where 3 products should be aligned in the same row, the first product stays on the right side and the other two go down to a new row. Checking the code with developer tools from Chrome/Firefox, there's no different classes or styles added to these products that would be causing the issue. The error also only seems to happen in bigger screens, so not a responsive issue.

All products are aligned left using an unordered list in CSS, with a fixed width of 300px for each product and a fixed width of 900px for the ul tag. No margins or paddings for li elements.

As I don't find this kind of browser-related issue, I don't know where to look at. I didn't develop this website but I'm working on fixing this issue. It doesn't use Bootstrap either.

Hope you guys can give me some clues.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, i loaded the page in Chrome and FF, and FF definitely screws up the list and I don't know why. I tried to create an MCVE demonstrating it, but was unsuccessful.

However, a fix is: Instead of `float:left` for the list items, use `display:inline-block`, and change the width of the `ul` from `900px` to `908px` to accommodate the extra space created by the inline block.

Answer (score 0):

Your product images are not of same size. That is making list items height different and layout is being messed up. Keep your images same sizes or you can apply this css.

```
.product-thumbnail {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.product-thumbnail::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 133.33%;
}
.product-thumbnail img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```